# `amb` operator as macro or procedure?

Tags: macros, scheme, non-deterministic

In [this](http://apisuckage.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/challenging-sicp/) page there is a comment after the post that gives a very short implementation of `amb` as a procedure:

```
(define (amb-backtrack)
  (error "no solution found"))

(define (amb . args)
  (call/cc (lambda (return)
             (let ((backtrack amb-backtrack))
               (map (lambda (x)
                      (call/cc (lambda (k)
                                 (set! amb-backtrack k)
                                 (return x))))
                    args)
               (backtrack 'fail)))))
```

But I usually see `amb` implemented as a macro -- in the schemers.org FAQ, and also in [Dorai Sitaram's book](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/t-y-scheme/t-y-scheme.html):

```
(define amb-fail '*)

(define initialize-amb-fail
  (lambda ()
    (set! amb-fail
      (lambda ()
        (error "amb tree exhausted")))))

(initialize-amb-fail)

(define-macro amb
  (lambda alts...
    `(let ((+prev-amb-fail amb-fail))
       (call/cc
        (lambda (+sk)

          ,@(map (lambda (alt)
                   `(call/cc
                     (lambda (+fk)
                       (set! amb-fail
                         (lambda ()
                           (set! amb-fail +prev-amb-fail)
                           (+fk 'fail)))
                       (+sk ,alt))))
                 alts...)

          (+prev-amb-fail))))))
```

So -- the macro version is longer, and a little harder to understand. I could not see any advantages of it over the procedure version, and of course I would rather use a procedure than a macro. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that a procedure call always evaluates all the arguments.

```
(amb 1 (very-expensive-computation))
```

will, with the procedure version of `amb`, perform the `very-expensive-computation`, then yield `1`. If yielding `1` suffices for all further computation, then you've wasted a lot of time on a computation whose result value is never used. Even worse things happen, as @Eli Barzilay mentions in a comment, when `amb` is used to model an infinite non-determinism such as generating all natural numbers.

The macro version avoids this and its behavior is therefore closer to that of non-deterministic programming languages such as Prolog.

Comment: "and its behavior is therefore closer to that of non-deterministic programming languages such as Prolog"--> Thank you! I knew the procedure would evaluate all arguments but I didn't think of the similarity of the macro version with nondeterministic programming in general.

Comment: It's much more than just wasting time -- consider a function with a second `amb` subform that calls the function in an infinite loop.  (That's not even some academic thing with no use: it would be a natural way to implement an `amb` for all integers.)  Such a thing would be impossible if `amb` is a plain function.

Comment: Lazy list are also possible in scheme, ok it is not the default.